# Vue App : content strangely changing in v-html directive

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

I'm dealing with a strange issue. I got a small content in my Vue app which changes sometimes in similar browsers (Google Chrome 83) as you can see in the two pictures : [Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7LAc.png) and [Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WeLNt.png) (sorry it's in French). 
The text displayed is embedded in a span with a v-html directive.

Do you think the issue comes from the browser ? Someone has already seen this issue ?

Thanks !

Comment: Can you better explain the problem? You need normal text, but your new was uppercased?

Comment: Paste the HTML in the question, it's hard to tell without it

Comment: `<div class="ortho-questions-cours-description">
    <v-row>
      <v-col md="12" sm="12" cols="12">
        <span v-html="questionB.cours_id[0].description"></span>
      </v-col>
  </v-row>
 </div>`

In my case, the text is HTML elements such as `<strong>`from a CKEditor

Comment: Can you share the content of `questionB.cours_id[0].description` please?

Comment: `<div>Si tu accordes avec un nom au pluriel  ajoute un <strong>-s</strong>.</div>`

Comment: Do you think some Google extensions can create this ?